# UITableView in UINavigationController gets under Navigation Bar after rotation

Tags: uitableview, uinavigationcontroller, rotation, bounds

This is Portrait:

[image]

This is Landscape

[image]

I've tried this on rotation with no success:

```
self.tableView.autoresizesSubviews = YES;
self.tableView.autoresizingMask = UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleHeight | UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleWidth;
```

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I ran into this problem recently.  In my case, it was because I was performing rotations of a navigation controller that was not the root controller of the application window.  I was therefore using the rotate notification listener/affine transform/bounds adjustment approach to changing the layout of the navigation controller.  This worked all right but produced the results described here.  It took me a while to notice that when I rotated to landscape the nav bar's height was not being correctly resized (i.e., from 44 to 32 pixels, the framework's reduced height for landscape mode).  The root view controller of my app **was** responding to **willRotateToInterfaceOrientation** and **didRotateFromInterfaceOrientation**, however.  That view controller also already knew about the associated navigation controller.  I remedied the problem by adding the following code to the **willRotateToInterfaceOrientation** method:

```
CGRect frame = self.navViewController.navigationBar.frame;
if (toInterfaceOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait || toInterfaceOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationPortraitUpsideDown) {
    frame.size.height = 44;
} else {
    frame.size.height = 32;
}
self.navViewController.navigationBar.frame = frame;
```

Hope this saves somebody some time in a similar situation.

Comment: Thanks. Unfortunately in my case the nav bar is changing height properly.  It seems that the view being shown loses all knowledge of the nav bar when rotated, so the top of it appears under the nav bar.  When another view is pushed and then popped, the problematic view is redistributed correctly.  I tried setNeedsLayout, but no avail.

Comment: Thanks, worked perfectly. Though you can use `(UIInterfaceOrientationIsPortrait(toInterfaceOrientation))` instead for your if condition to make it a little cleaner. Or even better something like: `frame.size.height = UIInterfaceOrientationIsPortrait(toInterfaceOrientation) ? 44. : 32.;`

Comment: First, this worked for me, which is annoying. Second, I found that putting the code in 'willRotate' to work better than in 'didRotate' (which seemed to cause a visual jump). Third, I think this is happening in my case because my root controller is a tab bar, and the individual tab has a navigation controller. As @jstevenco notes, the root controller is getting the orientation calls, not the nav controller. I wonder if there is something cleaner: a way for the root controller to tell the nav controller to layout its subviews, please?

Answer (score 7):

When using a custom view controller as root, which manages other view controllers itself, then it is responsible to forward all rotation events to the currently active sub-controller (if I may call it like that). These events are:

```
– willRotateToInterfaceOrientation:duration:

– willAnimateRotationToInterfaceOrientation:duration:

– didRotateFromInterfaceOrientation:

– willAnimateFirstHalfOfRotationToInterfaceOrientation:duration:

– didAnimateFirstHalfOfRotationToInterfaceOrientation:

– willAnimateSecondHalfOfRotationFromInterfaceOrientation:duration:
```

So in the case of a navigation controller, managed by your custom root controller, forwarding `– willAnimateRotationToInterfaceOrientation:duration:` to the navigation controller fixes the issue with the wrong navigation bar height when rotating.

Comment: This is the cleanest solution.

Comment: This should be the accepted answer. Also, note that in iOS 5 and 6, you can automatically forward rotation and appearance methods.

Answer (score 6):

Add the following line in the didRotateFromInterfaceOrientation method.

[self.navigationController.view layoutSubviews];

I hope this will do.

Answer (score 2):

I have exactly the same issue, and @jstevenco led me to a really strange solution.
My views also auto resize on rotation, but the tableview doesn't seem to understand there is a navigationcontroller sitting there:

Within the tableviewcontroller, add the following:

```
- (void)didRotateFromInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)fromInterfaceOrientation
{
[super didRotateFromInterfaceOrientation:fromInterfaceOrientation];
 CGRect frame = navBar.frame;
if (fromInterfaceOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait || fromInterfaceOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationPortraitUpsideDown) {
    frame.size.height = 31.9;
} else {
    frame.size.height = 44.1;
}
navBar.frame = frame;  

}
```

The 31.9 and 44.1 are very important strangly! Leaving these are 32 and 44, there is no resizing to do, so it seems to ignore it. Worked for me, hope it helps someone else.

Answer (score 0):

I looks like the table view is scrolled down a little after the orientation change.

Have you tried calling [`scrollToRowAtIndexPath:atScrollPosition:animated:`](http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UITableView_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/UITableView/scrollToRowAtIndexPath:atScrollPosition:animated:) and scrolling to the top-most row?

Comment: No, it's not that cause when you sweep down it comes again under the Navigation Bar. In the down side there's also a toolbar with same results. The down part of tableView is under it in Landscape mode

Answer (score 0):

This problem can occur if you've called "willAnimateRotationToInterfaceOrientation:" in your navigation controller, but forgotten to call super from within the method.

You should have something like this:

```
        - (void)willAnimateRotationToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)toInterfaceOrientation duration:(NSTimeInterval)duration {
        [super willAnimateRotationToInterfaceOrientation:toInterfaceOrientation];
// Your code here

    }
```

Comment: If I add that code I get this warning when I compile:

'UITableViewController' may not respond to '-willAnimateRotationToInterfaceOrientation:'

Comment: The code snippet needs to go into your navigation controller, not your TVC.

Comment: If I add that code I get this warning when I compile: 'UIViewController' may not respond to '-willAnimateRotationToInterfaceOrientation:' -Suchita

Comment: I too get a warning if I put this in either my tableViewController or my navigationController.

Answer (score 0):

One thing to look out for in these situations is the orientation of the Status Bar if you are changing it manually.  If the status bar is not hidden and you change the frame of your view while the status bar is in the wrong orientation (in your code, maybe you're updating the orientation of the status bar just after the frame change), it will auto resize the navigation bar wrongly, even if you haven't got auto resize on.

Answer (score 0):

Your `UINavigationController` needs to get notified when the device orientation changes. This doesn't happen if you only add the `view` of a `UINavigationController` to another `UIView`.

Starting with iOS 5, you can simply call `addChildViewController:` on the parent `UIViewController`, which will ensure that orientation changes are propagated to this child view controller.