# Auto-rotation on navigationBar

Tags: iphone, resize, uinavigationbar, autorotate

I've got a `navigationBar` that does not auto-resize when rotating the device anymore. So the navigationBar keeps it's portrait height of 44 pixels and does not shrink down to 32 pixels. I'm using a custom `UITabBarController` subclass which initializes the `UINavigationController`s and adds them to it's `viewControllers` array. Since I'm adding a `UIImageView` as a custom background to the `navigationBar` – which is being updated nicely when rotating – I always see the 12 pixel difference under my custom view. This differnce overlaps the `UITableView` also by the 12 pixels. So everything seems to be working fine – except the ordinary `UINavigationBar`. Did anyone ever have this issue and found a solution?

Thanks
–f

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1882107/uitableview-in-uinavigationcontroller-gets-under-navigation-bar-after-rotation/2867844#2867844) answered my question and worked for me. But I'm still not sure if that's the 'right' solution since the templates do it right automatically.