# why don't my navigationbars resize?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch, uinavigationbar

I have a tab bar based app.
In each tab I have a navigation controller.
Under each navigation controller I have table views.

When I rotate the device the navigation bars do not resize.
When I switch tabs the navigation bars do resize.

Any ideas what the problem might be? I've spent hours trying to figure it out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are several answers you can try from here. I recommend that you do a search. [This one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1882107/uitableview-in-uinavigationcontroller-gets-under-navigation-bar-after-rotation/2867844#2867844) in particular helped my case.

Comment: I don't know why I didn't find that when I did search, but thanks, it solved my problem.