# UITableView Misalignment with Navigation Bar (cells get stuck underneath on rotate)

Tags: objective-c, uitableview, uinavigationcontroller, scroll

I'm using the new Storyboarding feature in Xcode 4.2, and I've run into a problem *where my UITableView seems to forget that there is a Navigation Bar upon device rotation*. When the device is rotated, the cells appear to be **trapped** under the Navigation Bar. This bug is driving me absolutely insane, where I might just trash the project and start over.

Since I have recently noticed this, I am not sure if it is something that I had done / misconfigured or a bug. Nevertheless, to the issue:

---

### Images of the Issue:

The image below shows what my application looks like once loaded. Everything is aligned **correctly**

[image: Before Rotation]

Once the device is rotated, the UITableView ignores the Navigation Bar and assumes its space.

[image: During Rotation]

The problem persists even when the device is reoriented to portrait mode.

[image: After Rotation]

---

My struts and springs in Xcode are no different from a default UINavigationController dragged out from the object library. I've even ditched my UINavigationController and reconfigured a new one.

For the record, I do NOT have my main navigation controller subclassed.

Lastly, there is a similar [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1882107/uitableview-in-uinavigationcontroller-gets-under-navigation-bar-after-rotation) on Stack Overflow, but as you can see, my Navigation Bar **does** resize itself correctly upon rotation.

Comment: Have you checked the `Autoresize Subviews` settings?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add this in the didRotateFromInterfaceOrientation method.

[self.navigationController.view layoutSubviews];

Comment: Something so simple. This fixed my issue.

Answer (score 1):

Looks like you have `wantsFullScreenLayout = YES` in the `UIViewController`.

Comment: That, or he has a navigation controller with a translucent navigation bar, which always allows underlapping.

Comment: @dzeikei None of my view controllers have that set, but amazing idea. The translucent navigation bar was set just for example so I could show the the UITableView assumed its space.